# Balanced binary cycle

Tags: number-sequence

Let's call a binary cycle ${\bf x}:x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{12}$ *balanced* if exactly 6 of the $x_i$'s are 0 and 6 of them are 1. We can place the sequence around a circle and add each two adjacent digits modulo 2 to obtain a new binary cycle, so the new cycle has terms $f({\bf x}):x_1+x_2, x_2+x_3, \ldots, x_{11}+x_{12}, x_{12}+x_1$ modulo 2. Now, consider the following binary cycle:
$${\bf x}: 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.$$
It happens that $f({\bf x})$ is also balanced:
$$f({\bf x}):1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,$$
and $f(f({\bf x}))$ is also balanced:
$$f(f({\bf x})): 0, 0, 1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1.$$
However, $f(f(f({\bf x})))$ is  not balanced:
$$f(f(f({\bf x}))): 0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1.$$
Can you find a binary cycle ${\bf x}$ of length 12 such that ${\bf x}, f({\bf x}),f(f({\bf x})),$ and $f(f(f({\bf x})))$ are all balanced?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this puzzle can be approached manually, but testing all such cycles via code reveals a solution that is unique up to cyclic shifts, reversals and inversions.

> \begin{align}x:0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1\\ f(x):0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1\\ f(f(x)):0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1\\ f(f(f(x))):0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're looking for, there are either

> 48 solutions, or 1

Counting all cycles, there are

> 48 solutions to this problem, as listed below:
>
>  $[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]$

But these are all the same, just shifted, inverted or reversed - or a combination. There is therefore

> 1 'unique' answer - any of the above cycles, say $[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]$ for example.
>
> All other cycles can be made from this cycle ([note @Daniel Mathias found this first!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/117768/18250))

---

I knocked up some code to generate all 4096 different binary cycles, then filter out those which aren't 'balanced'.

From there a bit of code to generate $f(x)$, $f(f(x))$, $f(f(f(x)))$ and check if those were balanced allowed you to backtrack to find the original cycle.

$f(x)$, $f(f(x))$ and $f(f(f(x)))$ listed below for the solutions above for reference:

> $f(x)$:
>
> $[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]$
>
> $f(f(x))$:
>
> $[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]$
>
> $f(f(f(x)))$:
>
> $[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]$

Comment: They are actually all the same solution.

Comment: Take the reverse of (1) and shift it one position to the left to get (3)

Comment: @DanielMathias surely by logic, there should be 2 answers? For a unique cycle, you can choose any of the 12 numbers, and go left or right - giving 12*2 = 24 cycles that are the same. I've found 48 cycles total - so does that not indicate the existence of 2 answers? Also I don't think doing that to 1 creates 3 - 3 has 4 1's in a row whereas 1 does not

Comment: The other is inversion: $001001010111\equiv110110101000$

Comment: @DanielMathias ah thats what I was missing, and that makes sense why it then doubles - will leave my answer up or it'll feel like a waste of time and code (I'm awful at coding) , but you should def get the tick for getting it first!

Answer (score 1):

Really nice puzzle.

> We know that $x_1 + ... + x_{12} = 6$.
>  $(x_1+x_2) + (x_2+x_3) + ... + (x_{12}+x_1) = 12$ 
>  $(x_1+x_2) mod 2 + (x_2+x_3) mod 2 + ... + (x_{12}+x_1) mod 2 = 6$
>  This means there must be 3 instances of two 1s in a row, which lead to 0 at the next stage. There must be 6 instances of two opposite numbers next to each other for the next series to have 6 1s. The remaining 3 are 00s. That means there must be three uninterrupted blocks of both numbers each, and the next stages must be formed accordingly.
>  This picture can help with finding a way: 
> [image] 
>  A possible solution will be 100001101011 (and its rotations). Both 0000s and 1111s can't appear together, because that would lead to the uninterrupted blocks being fewer than three each.